# How to add a new named group?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following working pattern:

```
String pattern = @"<(?<field>[^/>]+)>(?<data>.*)</\k<field>>";


String tcSQML = "<Pri_Key1>62</Pri_Key1><First1>SAM</First1><Last1>SPADE</Last1>  <GstNo1></GstNo1><Pri_Key2>63</Pri_Key2><First2>TONY</First2><Last2>TUNE</Last2><GstNo2></GstNo2><Pri_Key3>64</Pri_Key3><First3>FRANK</First3><Last3>FAST</Last3><GstNo3></GstNo3><Pri_Key4>65</Pri_Key4><First4>BILLIE</First4><Last4>BLADES</Last4><GstNo4></GstNo4>";
     MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(tcSQML, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
     foreach (Match m in matches)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["field"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["number"].ToString());

     }
```

What I want is to be able to also capture number after the field. E.g. in pri_key1 pri_key should be the field and 1 should be the number. I can not figure out how to introduce this new Number group into this pattern. I tried a few variations and nothing works. I am not good with RegEx so help and explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's untested:

```
String pattern = @"<(?<field>[^0-9/>]+)(?<number>[^/>]*)>(?<data>.*)</\k<field>\k<number>>";
```

I just added a new group behind the field element. The new field element matches any string that does not contain a digit or the `/` or the `>` characters. The number element matches anything that is left between the field and the end of the tag.

Comment: How can I change this pattern if the field tag is known? Say, this is a new string 
"<Del_Pri_Key1>62</Del_Pri_Key1><Del_Pri_Key2>63</Del_Pri_Key2>"; 
So, my tag is Del_Pri_Key

Comment: Just remove `(?<field>[^0-9/>]+)` and replace it with your known tag name. You also have to replace `\k<field>` with your tag name.

Comment: This is what I tried - not working
pattern = @"<del_pri_key(?<number>[^/>]*)>(?<data>.*)/del_pri_key\k<number>>";

tcSQML = "<Del_Pri_Key1>62</Del_Pri_Key1><Del_Pri_Key2>63</Del_Pri_Key2>";
          matches = Regex.Matches(tcSQML, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
         foreach (Match m in matches)
         {
            //Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["field"].ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["number"].ToString());
               
         }